# How can I find where an @InvocableMethod is used?

Tags: invocable-method

Given a class with an `@InvocableMethod`, how can I determine where the InvocableMethod is actually being used?  Apex Classes don't have a "Where is this used?" button, only a "Show Dependencies" button, which doesn't show where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to delete the class will fail if something is using it, and will helpfully report what is using the class.  On the other hand, if it is not in use, the deletion will occur, which may not be desired.  But it is possible to run a test deletion with either Ant or SFDX.  SFDX is simpler:

```
sfdx force:source:delete -c -p force-app/main/default/Invocable.cls
```

Be sure to include the `-c` (or `--check-only`) flag to prevent an actual delete from occurring.  If the Invocable is used anywhere, `sfdx` will return an error listing where the class is used, such as flow(s) which reference the Invocable method.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this -

> You can perform a global search with search term as
> **@InvocableMethod** in VS Code if you have your org connected and have all the apex classes in your local repository. It will show all the files containing the search term.

**OR**

> The other way is you can open the developer console - For windows -
> press **Ctrl+Shift+H** and search for the **@InvocableMethod**. And if
> you are using macOS, then you can press **Cmd+Shift+H** and perform
> the search.

Comment: They want to search for usages of the invocable method - not the method declaration itself. They'd want to search with the Invocable apex class name as it'll appear within `<actionName>InvocableMethodClassName</actionName>` in flow metadata.